# How to find the nth highest value in a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

What is the logic in the below query to find the nth highest value in the table?

```
select * 
from tablename as a 
where (n-1) = (select count(distinct(column name) 
               from tablename as b 
               where b.columname > a.columnname)
```

Example query:

```
select * 
from tblperson a 
where 3 = (select count(distinct(expenses)) 
           from tblperson b 
           where b.Expenses > a.Expenses)
```

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Tag your question appropriately.  You tagged it "SQL" which is "structured query language" not "SQL Server".

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind this query

Comment: What specifically are you confused about?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function [OFFSET FETCH Clause (SQL Server Compact)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx):

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY expenses DESC
OFFSET N - 1 ROWS -- Nth highest (N-1 offset)
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: forgive my briefness because im on my phone but this could help.  Your statement retrieves an ordered list, because the list is in order by rank,  simply append `OFFSET n LIMIT 1` and it will return a single item located at the nth element in the ordered list thus yielding the desired result.

Comment: @JakePsimos that would work if the OP was using mysql. However, they clearly stated they are using sql server.

Comment: @JakePsimos, thanks for your hint. My answer was wrong, please see my update, the `OFFSET` in MS SQL.

Comment: @SeanLange, although it is not MySQL here, his tip still makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The query says for every row go and count how many unique values are in the table with a greater value (in a particular column) than the one I'm looking at. Keep only those (ties possible) that fall at a certain position. So for 4th place you'll expect to find 3 values that are higher.

This is accomplished by way of the inner query which is called a correlated subquery. Although the server is likely to have a more efficient way of actually calculating the results you can think of it as a a lot like a loop with a function call. The inner query is logically executed once for every row in the outer query and the reference(s) to `a` inside it are constant for each of these runs.

Rewriting it this way may help you understand. (And you can also test the inner query by itself.)

```
select * from
(
    select
        a.columnname,
        (
            select count(distinct columnname)
            from tablename as b 
            where b.columnname > a.columnname
        ) as NumRowsGreater
    from tablename as a
) as t
where NumRowsGreater = (n-1)
```

Comment: My doubt here is, the sub query will return the number of count of which the where condition is satisfied, but how the main query returns the max value since it compares only the value "where (n-1) = "

Comment: @Thulasiram I can't really pinpoint your confusion so I can explain it better. Study my explanation because I think you don't understand how the correlation works.

Answer (score 0):

in SQL-Server try this

```
select TOP 3 * FROM tblperson order by Expenses DESC
```

OR something like this in the stored procedures

```
select TOP @N * FROM tblperson order by Expenses DESC
```

Comment: Only the Nth row should be returned.